# Mobile stylesheet doesnt load when redirected

Tags: android, css, mobile, stylesheet

If i pull up my website in my Android 2.2 phone browser, it shows my mobile login stylesheet. If I login, the site redirects you to the dashboard page. It does not show my mobile stylesheet now! BUT, if I REFRESH it with Menu Button -> Refresh on my phone, it shows my mobile stylesheet! How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue that ended up being a result of Apache's basic auth. Are you password protecting your dashboard? If so, try disabling it.